# I'm trying to find the files in a folder on linux server, which has more than 1000 lines..?

Tags: find, lines, wc

I'm trying to find the files in a folder on server, which has more than 1000 lines..? 
Is it possible with single command using pipes.?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for files containing spaces and or other special characters:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0 -I '{}' awk 'NR > 1000 { print FILENAME; exit }' '{}'
```

And this should give improved performance using multi-core CPUs, but only if you have [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel -0 "awk 'NR > 1000 { print FILENAME; exit }'" ::: /path/to/files
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

```
wc -l /myDir/* | awk '{if($1 >= 1000) print $2;}' | grep -v total
```